# Handling databases 1 to n relationship in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in ror and the functionality I am working on is that each answer has n comments,

**my code for getting all answers**

```
@answers = Answer.get_answers_fro_question(params[:id])
```

now I am trying to get the comments against each row of answers

code is

```
 @answers.each do |answer|
    answer.my_comments = Comment.get_comments( related_to, answer.id )
 end
```

**this causes error, undefined method my_comments**

when I try this

```
 @answers.each do |answer|
        answer[:my_comments] = Comment.get_comments( related_to, answer.id )
 end
```

**and this causes error, can't write unknown attribute `my_comments'**

**Model code for Answer**

```
    def self.get_answers_fro_question(question_id)
        obj = Answer.where(question_id: question_id).joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = answers.user_id').select('users.username,answers.*')
        return obj
    end
```

**Model code for Comment**

```
    def self.get_comments(related_to, related_to_id)
        obj = Comment.where(related_to: related_to, related_to_id: related_to_id).joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = comments.user_id').select('users.username,users.file_name,comments.*')
        return obj
    end
```

I think this isn't the syntax in ror,
How can I achieve it, please help. I have searched a lot

Comment: what is `my_comments` ? What are you trying to do by this line `comment.my_comments` ?

Comment: `@answers.each do |comment|` shouldn't this be: `@answers.each do |answer|`?? Using variable names like that you will confuse yourself in future.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Well trying to make a new index, or variable

Comment: Can you show your answer and comment model files? How you have put associations between them?

Comment: @User089247, I have edited the code, please check